# In CQ5 what does $CQ(function(){ ... }) do?

Tags: jquery, aem

I'm learning CQ5 atm and in the generated HTML, I saw a line that looks like this:

```
$CQ(function(){
    initializeTeaserLoader( ....... );
});
```

I read somewhere that CQ has it's own implementation of the jquery library. Is this what I'm looking at? But with jquery, it uses the '$' to take a DOM elements as input before performing some actions on the element.

In this case though, it doesn't look like $CQ is taking any input. It just straight up calls a function, which calls another function.

So what does it actually mean? Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`$CQ` is just a namespace for CQ library. It could be anything. Dollar sign has no particular significance. It's just a regular character like a,b,c,1,2,3... Dollar sign is simply what jQuery chose to use by default.

You can create your own namespace:

```
//create your custom namespace for jQuery library
var SyniaJQuery = jQuery.noConflict();

//use it to find elements and do something with them
SyniaJQuery("#foo").doSomthing(...);
```

So `$CQ` is a default namespace for CQ library so it doesn't interfere with any other libraries using `$` as namespace for example.

Function:

```
$CQ(function(){
    ....
});
```

is equivalent in jQuery to:

```
 $(function(){
        ....
 });
```

This function executes on document load.